# Do iPhones send signals with IP address even after it has been turned off?

Tags: ip, iphone, tracking

My phone is gone and unfortunately it was turned off before I lost it. Is it possible for me to track it down with my IP address that I have saved? Because I read some articles that say that your phone doesn't turn off completely and I was thinking that maybe the phone was sending requests or are connected to the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use this method to try to track your phone. And even if if does transmit, how do you hope to use this information? Contact your mobile phone provider. They have all the tools to do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, iphone will not send request while it is turned off. For this "phone doesn't turn off completely", yes there is some cases but that topic is not for end users.

You can see its last coordinate seen online with "where is my phone" feature of Apple.